# How do you get the transfer functions in CIECA approach?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have been looking through "Current Injected Equivalent Circuit Approach To Modeling Switching DC-DC Converters" by P.R.K. CHETTY. But could not get the transfer function equations as derived in the paper. Any help/pointers in solving these would be much appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Paper: [IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4102601)

Comment: For anyone unwilling to use sci-hub to access the paper, it's currently behind a paywall. But just saying that you *"could not get the transfer function equations as derived in the paper"* isn't a good way to ask for help. You've shown none of your work effort. So how would anyone know what to write? A complete review of the paper and a dialog with someone willing to teach the paper to you? That's not happening here. You probably need to write enough so that someone here can zero in on a specific difficulty you face and help you cross that bridge. (Assuming they have time for it.)

Comment: That said, I cannot think of anyone here more likely to have read the paper and more likely better prepared to help than [Verbal Kint](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/141599/verbal-kint). This is one of his more advanced, specialized masteries. Skimming the paper itself its reasoning (motivation) seems almost obvious, though. They simply identify the non-linear switching part of it and create a linearized model to use for it. The rest is linear, by definition. Seems like the obvious path to follow.

Comment: If the goal is to learn how to model dc-dc converters, I recommend you consider the PWM switch model, introduced by V. Vorpérian in 1986. This is the easiest and fastest way to determine transfer functions of switching converters without resorting to an equivalent ac model. Have a look at my APEC 2013 [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) for small-signal techniques applied to the modeling of these converters. Also, my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) covers the subject in depth.

Comment: The idea behind modeling is to write *averaged* equations, meaning that you want to replace an equation which is discontinuous in time - the current in the power switch for instance exists during \$dT_{sw}\$ and is zero the rest of the time - by a time-continuous expression: how does this current look if I "stretch" the waveform along the entire switching period? You end-up with a large-signal nonlinear equation you must linearize before applying the Laplace transform. This is the process conveyed by the expressions you have reproduced but I am not convinced by the formalism the author used.